# See-through window using OpenGL stencil buffer

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to create a see-through window effect in OpenGL.
By means of a background quad, I render a background texture. After that, I render the see-through window texture on top and fill the stencil buffer with ones everywhere the window is. Finally, I render a mesh only where the stencil buffer has ones.

Here is my OpenGL initialization code and my `Draw`method:

```
// OpenGL state
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);



// Draw method
auto virtual Draw() -> void override
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Update camera UBO
    ...

    // Render background
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    prg_texture2D->UseProgram();
        prg_texture2D->SetUniform("modelMatrix", glm::mat4());
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            tex_image->Bind();
                backgroundQuad->Render();
            tex_image->Unbind();
    prg_texture2D->UnUseProgram();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

    // Render window
    double x, y;
    glfwGetCursorPos(m_window, &x, &y);
    glViewport(x - 150, m_windowDimensions.y - y - 150, 300, 300); // see-through window size = 300
    glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
    glStencilMask(0xFF);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    prg_texture2D->UseProgram();
        prg_texture2D->SetUniform("modelMatrix", glm::mat4());
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            tex_window->Bind();
                backgroundQuad->Render();
            tex_window->Unbind();
    prg_texture2D->UnUseProgram();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    backgroundQuad->UpdatePositions(vec_positions);
    glViewport(0, 0, m_windowDimensions.x, m_windowDimensions.y);

    // Update camera UBO
    ...

    // Render skull
    glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFF);
    glStencilMask(0x00);
    prg_lighting->UseProgram();
        skull->ResetModelMatrix();
        skull->ScaleModel(glm::vec3(0.005f, 0.005f, 0.005f));
        skull->RotateModel(glm::radians(180.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        prg_lighting->SetUniform("modelMatrix", skull->GetModelMatrix());
        skull->Render(GL_TRIANGLES);
    prg_lighting->UnUseProgram();
```

Without the calls to `glViewport`, the see-through texture is streched across the whole screen, which is not what want as the window should be movable. However, in this case, the stencil functionality works fine and the mesh (which I can rotate, translate, etc.) is only visible if behind the see-through window.

With the calls to `glViewport`, the behavious is very strange and the stencil test passes for every portion of the screen where the see-through window has been moved since the start of the program, i.e. if I move the see-through window over the entire screen, the mesh is visible all the time.

Instead of changing the viewport, I also tried to update the vertex positions of the background quad which I use to render the textures to the screen. However, the effect is exactly the same. Here is the code using the background quad update:

```
// Render window
double x, y;
glfwGetCursorPos(m_window, &x, &y);
float p = 0.1; // size of see-through window
std::array<glm::vec3, 6> vec_windowPositions = // All in the range of [-1, 1]
{
    // First triangle
    glm::vec3(2 * (x / m_windowDimensions.x - p / 2) - 1, 2 * ((m_windowDimensions.y - y) / m_windowDimensions.y - p / 2) - 1, 0.0f), // {0}
    glm::vec3(2 * (x / m_windowDimensions.x + p / 2) - 1, 2 * ((m_windowDimensions.y - y) / m_windowDimensions.y - p / 2) - 1, 0.0f), // {1}
    glm::vec3(2 * (x / m_windowDimensions.x + p / 2) - 1, 2 * ((m_windowDimensions.y - y) / m_windowDimensions.y + p / 2) - 1, 0.0f), // {2}

     // Second triangle
    glm::vec3(2 * (x / m_windowDimensions.x + p / 2) - 1, 2 * ((m_windowDimensions.y - y) / m_windowDimensions.y + p / 2) - 1, 0.0f), // {2}
    glm::vec3(2 * (x / m_windowDimensions.x - p / 2) - 1, 2 * ((m_windowDimensions.y - y) / m_windowDimensions.y + p / 2) - 1, 0.0f), // {3}
    glm::vec3(2 * (x / m_windowDimensions.x - p / 2) - 1, 2 * ((m_windowDimensions.y - y) / m_windowDimensions.y - p / 2) - 1, 0.0f)  // {0}
};
backgroundQuad->UpdatePositions(vec_windowPositions); // Update new vertex positions
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFF);
glStencilMask(0xFF);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
prg_texture2D->UseProgram();
    prg_texture2D->SetUniform("modelMatrix", glm::mat4());
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        tex_window->Bind();
            backgroundQuad->Render();
        tex_window->Unbind();
prg_texture2D->UnUseProgram();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
backgroundQuad->UpdatePositions(vec_positions); // Update to old, fulscreen vertex positions
```

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like. Any suggestions how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Hey, you should provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Otherwise it is really hard to make sense of your code and help you, even though people are willing to help. The same applies to your previous question.

Comment: I got the impression that you ran into the exactly same issue like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548848/issue-when-updating-stencil-buffer-in-opengl/33553747#33553747), but I can't be sure from the code posted so far.

Comment: take a look at my code for very similar thing [I have an OpenGL Tessellated Sphere and I want to cut a cylindrical hole in it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39466130/2521214) to compare what is different. I do not use glViewPort for this.

Comment: @derhass: Thanks you so much for your answer! Thanks to your reference and moving the call to `glClear(STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)` after the call to `glStencilMask`, both versions I posted (background quad & vierport change) work perfectly fine! Maybe you can post your comment as an answer such that I can mark the issue as solved.